# Android Studio import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP

Tags: android-studio, ftp

I'm trying to import the library org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP but I don't know how to do it correctly. I found other posts but without updated solutions. I've already added into gradle file, the string: `implementation 'org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-net:6.5.0.Final'` and also tried to download the library from: `File -> ProjectStructure -> LibraryDependency` but I can't find it.

Also, if I download the zip from: `https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi` I don't understand where to place it and still android studio can't find:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Download the "commons-net-3.9.0-bin.zip" from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi
2. Extract the zip and using Android Studio place the "commons-net-3.9.0.jar" file into your `ProjectName -> App -> Libs` folder
3. Right click in the file and select at the bottom "Add As Library"

I didn't add anything into gradle file

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dependency in your `build.gradle.kts` and that's all, just click gradle sync then.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("commons-net:commons-net:3.9.0")
}
```